# Launch Image of my iPhone App cannot be launched while running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Apple rejected my app for the reason **2.10: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
Information Needed**

Here is my launch image 
[image]

Here is apple's reply:
[image]

My code is at github: https://github.com/imWildCat/V2EX-iOS

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is about your app icons / launch image.

What I suggest is that you Build and run on your iPad simulator and see how your app is rendering / behaving. 
A valid result is a perfect representation / functionality of your app on an iPad (with some black boarders that will be there automatically since the screen proportions are not time same between iPhone and iPad)

it seems to me that your reviewer was testing your app on an iPad and something was just not working (visually) - most likely some user input screens

I would also make sure all the meta-data on i-connect is valid.

Comment: My app works okay on iPad(both on simulator and device) except not displaying the launch image.

Comment: Ok, clear all the images and redo them one by one with with great attention to sizes. I would recommend you save the problematic images again via photoshop - in particular iPad icon(s).